# Is there a way to speed up Jsoup.parse()?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using the all String version of Jsoup.parse():

```
parse(String html, String baseUri)
```

Ruling out connectivity speed for benchmarking its performance.

On a typical low-end Android phone, calling `Jsoup.parse()` on the html String of a not-so-rare long Wikipedia page (~600KB), takes **9 seconds**!

My client is not willing to accept this delay and I am thinking of either dumping Jsoup for a different engine, parsing web pages myself (still in Java), or using some C/C++ parser in NDK (if available).

But I prefer continuing to use Jsoup as much as possible.

Is there a way to speed up `Jsoup.parse()`?

Comment: It might help if you would explain what you are planning on doing with the parsed page.

Comment: @CommonsWare Display certain parts of the HTML page in different ways, using Jsoup's well known `select()` syntax. I can't use Jsoup's `select()` before Jsoup's parsing is over.

Comment: Yah this has happened to me as well.  The Jsoup.parse is definitely a performance hog, and I think when you couple that it with Java memory thrashing on Android devices which have limited memory, the results could be quite bad.  In the past I've improved my performance by just not using parse when I don't have to - for example using regular expressions / string manipulation to extract info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I try to do myself with big pages (**if it's possible** and you only want some information on the page) is try to minimize the text to parse identifying previously the regions that you want and then parse wanted regions with JSoup.

That way you can combine your own parsing in Java to reduce data and then use JSoup for commodity.